# Cannot convert string to float from tkinter entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am basically making a program where users can input different numbers to get the area and perimeter answers for a certain shape. Now, I am using the Tkinter module for the GUI and for some reason I do not even have a string for the entry. My code is as follows (for the entry of numbers):

```
def perTriangle():
    tk.Label(window, text = "Enter in the Numbers: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 100)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 1: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 130)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry1.place(x = 1155, y = 130)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 2: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 160)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry2.place(x = 1155, y = 160)
    tk.Label(window, text = "Side 3: ", background = "white").place(x = 1115, y = 190)
    entry3 = tk.Entry(window)
    entry3.place(x = 1155, y = 190)
    btnA = tk.Button(mainFrame, text = "Enter", fg = "black", command = btnACommand).place(x = 1115, y = 220)
    num1 = float(entry1.get())
    num2 = float(entry2.get())
    num3 = float(entry3.get())
```

Now I cannot convert between a string and a float because I don't even have a string (I think this is the case but I may be wrong). The error message I get is:

```
num1 = float(entry1.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. It seems as though everything I'm doing is alright.
I appreciate any and all help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did not test yet what `entry1.get()` returns? That is the underlying *cause* of the error.

Comment: You are trying to convert the values about a millisecond after the widget is created, well before the user even sees the input widget much less type in it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your trying to convert an empty string to an floating point integer because when you get() the contents of the entry box, its only milliseconds after it was created not giving the user enough time to enter their preference

What you need to do is create it along with a submit button that, when clicked, will get the values of the entry boxes where you can do further checking using the following code:

```
try:
    float(entry1.get())
except ValueError:
    #do something when failed
```

this should help

Comment: That won't help in this case. The root cause is that they are calling the `get` method before the user has a chance to enter any data.

Comment: @BryanOakley Your right, i will keep this up but edit it